# Can I safely jumper between either G or Y and RC at thermostat panel to troubleshoot AC problem?

Tags: hvac, thermostat

I'm trying to troubleshoot a non-functioning AC.  The fan does not come on and there is no cool air/condenser does not run.

My thermostat is a Braeburn.  Three things I'd like to try for troubleshooting, but are they safe:

- Can I safely just jumper between the G and RC posts at the thermostat
  to see if the ran comes on?
- Can I do the same between the Y and RC posts?
- I have other Braeburn faceplates (the AC and the heat are separate
  systems and the house has 4 zones for heat so I can 'borrow' a
  faceplate from another location) - can I safely pop one of those on
  the one thermostat that controls the AC to see if the Braeburn is
  shot?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "Yes you can", but I would hesitate giving a DIY this information without knowing how much experience he has in controls and troubleshooting. True a thermostat is simply a set of switches but you are also bypassing many protective devices used to stop a sequence to protect your equipment. This type of procedure in my circles is infamously known as a "smoke test" or a test of last resort. So if you decided to do it. Be prepared to replace other parts you may damage.

Good luck.